# Automatically height adjusting div

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have a page and in that page, I have two divs, one named 'bar' and another named 'example'. The code is something like :

```
<style>
#example{

    float:right;

}
#bar {
  width: 100px;
  height:100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
</style>

<div id="example"><p>This is page content</p><p>This is page content</p></div>
<div id="bar"></div>
```

Now, I'll copy and paste the paragraph within the `<p>` tag, something like hundred times inside the div 'example', so the height of my page will increase. I want my div to automatically adjust its height with the new height of the page after I copy-paste the paragraph hundred times, so that the div will cover top to bottom of my page. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've fully understood the question, but from what I gather, you are trying to make the div the height of the div be at least the height of the screen. If so, setting it's height to `min-height: 100vh` should do the trick. When your code says "height: 100%" as it does now, it just means "make this div 100% of the parent div's height" rather than the height of the screen.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
    #bar{
       height:auto;
    }
```

That should do the trick.

E: Your goal wasn't outlined 100% and after running your code it looks messy so I assumed you wanted the `bar` content to be inside `example` so I adjusted it. If you want to remove the line that separates them just take out the `p` and `p:first-of-type` styles.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #example {
      float: right;
    }
    
    #bar {
      width: 100px;
      height: auto;
      border: 1px solid red;
      box-sizing: border-box
    }
    
    p {
      border-top: 1px solid red;
      padding-top: 10px;
    }
    
    p:first-of-type {
      border: none;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <div id="example">
      <div id="bar">
        <p>This is page content</p>
        <p>This is page content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

And if you want the text centered in the box just do `p{text-align:center;}`

Comment: example and bar are two separate divs. They are not related to each other. bar contains some content while example contains fully different content. I was trying to find a way where these two different divs' height will be always same and the height will be the bigger one's height. I want this to be adjusted automatically.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PHjtJ/ Check out this JS that lets you do exactly that. Credits to Charles Ingalls[http://stackoverflow.com/users/1874138/charles-ingalls]